# Autopopulate a field in a form based on what user is logged in

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, auto-populate

I've created an access database using access 2007 for one of the teams I work with and I'm fairly new to access so would like some help. The database is being used to log jobs for engineers so I have a login system where a user selects their name from a drop down and enters their password, and depending on their access levels they get directed to their own user menus etc. Now what I would like is once the user has logged in they will click on the job sheet button will then direct them to a list of jobs raised from here they click on new and then a pop of the Job Sheet where they can enter details from the call pops up what i want is in this job sheet for their name to auto-populate in the field labelled user, how do I get the user who has logged in their name to just auto populate in the field once they have accessed it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the "OnLoad" property of the form. Go to the properties section of the job sheet and click on its "on load" event. Select VBA code. Type the following:-

me.*fieldname* = [Forms]![*FirstFormWhereLoginDropdownPresent*].*DropDownName*.Value

Hope this helps